# Remote control of iPad (from a PC ideally)?

Tags: ipad, remote-desktop

I've had a quick look through the search results, and am not able to find a suitable answer.

My scenario is this - my mother in law in her 70s, is not all that keen on technology. She's also self-isolated thanks to Corona.

We're sending an iPad her way, that we can get 'set up' in advance... but what we really need to be able to do is remote-support it, because we can't go and see her in person.

To that end, I'm wondering what the best option would be for remote support. We have available an iPhone, a PC and an Android phone.

I'm currently contemplating something like teamviewer (the 'quick support' looks to allow screen *viewing* which would be a start), but if there's a free option out there that'd be better still.

Comment: Looks like putting the question on hold wasn't the best of ideas, Teamviewer indeed has a solution for this. AFAIK there still isn't a way to remotely *control* an iDevice.

Comment: This is a catch 22. Security wise, you need user interaction to take over a device, but your reason for taking over the device is because of the user’s limited ability to interact with it.  What function do you want her to use? FaceTime?  Create a pictorial step-by-step to get her going and print it out.  Put colored stickers (post-its) on the device itself so she knows what to press.  Start small, she’ll pick up quickly. Most of all pretend to know nothing about tech and follow your instructions to ensure it works

Comment: My reason for wanting to interact is to help reassure an elderly person that it's working fine, and there's nothing she can do to 'break' it persistently. And occasionally fiddle with the settings and assist with getting new stuff installed. I can't put coloured stickers on the device, if I can't physically be present. It's fine to be require remote user interaction to enable the remote access.

Comment: This may totally not be helpful but my 85 year old Aunt got an iPad from me many years ago and she had a friend who live on the iPad. So her friend spent some time with her familiarizing her with the iPad and now she can't put it down! So maybe a bit of *social* engineering. Does she have a friend with an iPad?

Comment: The core reason we're trying to do this, is because of the self isolation and lockdown. So short answer is 'no' - there's no contact going to happen for at least a couple of weeks more.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399075/drop-ship-a-preconfigured-ipad-to-elderly-in-laws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution we've found so far, is 'teamviewer quick support'.

It doesn't allow for remote control, but it does permit screen sharing. An app on the iPad generates a 'connection ID' and a remote client on a desktop system can then connect to it, and view the screen.

It's not exactly what we wanted, but it's sufficient to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordinary MDM software to manage the device to ensure that you can remotely control settings, install apps and make sure the user does not "break" the device.

Actual remote control is not possible on a system-wide level, unless you connect the iPad to a remote KVM type hardware. You can get remote control in a single app with apps that have that feature (mostly enterprise software).

You can get remote viewing using software like TeamViewer and ZoHo Assist.