# Drop ship a preconfigured iPad to elderly in-laws?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud

My elderly inlaws need "The Video Phone" to work. I'd like to drop ship a pre-configured iPad that just connects to Wifi / logs into iCloud so we can see each other.

In fact, the existing onsite iPad has been fine for two years until it was mysteriously auto-logged out of iCloud...

My goals are to:

- Configure a Wifi SSID / password in advance.
- Spoof or fake and store the MacAddress of a given SSID to pre-join their network.

What setup is realistic for this case?

Comment: Get it delivered to you, install and configure it then post it to them .

Comment: If the old iPad has iCloud Keychain on, then it's just a matter of restoring the new iPad from an iCloud backup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Amazingly, iOS does not seem to store the SSID MAC Addr so this might just work...

Comment: A "BSSID" is a MAC address. An "SSID" is the WiFi network's name.  If you had a WiFi network with multiple access points, but wanted a device to only ever use one specific access point (e.g. force a WiFi security camera to only use the access point with the strongest signal) then you could use the BSSID.  An SSID never locks to just one MAC address.

Comment: The SSID is all that’s checked when enrolling and this is how you can have a wide campus with dozens of hotspots, each the same SSID and multiple  MAC address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question - the answer is no, the SSID/MAC address of the base station is not paired up. Thank you all for the advise, the plan worked. Shipper at 100% power and received at 20%, auto-connected to WiFi for us to call and do the rest!

You can, however use mobile device management to automate add a large menu of options on both iOS, macOS, iPadOS, tvOS, watchOS.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/profile-specific_payload_keys

Wifi SSID is one that’s very common, but instead of your relatives needing to know how to enter WiFi, they need to be shown how to install a profile or remove one if things change.